# Magento 2 : Manually send current currency to a payment method in a multi currency store

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, multicurrency

I have to manually send price of the products in cart, tax, total etc.  in current currency to a payment method as by default magento sends it in base currency of the store.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is many extensions Available for Magento1 to achieve this functionality.

I've used this https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

You can take reference from this extension to achieve your goal in magento2